# Python - While condition - Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
condition=1

while { condition<10:

print("condition")

condition+=1

File "<stdin>", line 3
    condition+=1
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me to fix this Syntax Error in Python 3.6.4

Comment: Your `while` shouldn'tn have a `{`, this isn't C++

Comment: This isn't python.

Comment: You opened a brace and didn't close it.  The Python parser got to the end of the file without finding the matching right brace.  You have several errors in this; please pay close attention to your learning materials for proper Python syntax.

Comment: Also note that `print("condition")` will just print the word "condition", but not the value of the variable `condition`.

Comment: All - I am using Python version 3.6.4.

Comment: So why aren't you using Python syntax?

Comment: condition=1
while condition<10:
    print("condition")
    condition += 1

Comment: I have used the same code given by Pen in below comment. Am not getting any error now. But same time am not getting the output

Answer (score 1):

You have a `{` too much, and indentation too few:

```
condition=1
while condition<10:
    print("condition")
    condition += 1
```

Comment: >>> while condition<10:
... print("condition")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("condition")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: indentation is important. You have to use the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the curly bracket. Your code should be this:

```
condition=1

while condition<10:

   print("condition")

   condition+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
condition=1 
while condition<10: 
    print("condition") 
    condition+=1
```

Try this as python uses indentation instead of semicolon.

Comment: condition=1

while condition<10:

print("condition")
 
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("condition")
        ^

IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for your curly brace:

```
condition=1

while condition<10:

    print("condition")

    condition+=1
```

Comment: condition=1

while condition<10:

print("condition")
 
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("condition")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score -2):

I think u should use

```
While (condition){
 Condition+=condition
```

}

Comment: This alters the logic of the original posting.